# How to echo an image at a certain id in MySql table?

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I am having a little trouble trying to display the image at ID: 2 in my store table...

here's what i've come up with (p.s. the reason I set $id = 2 is because I plan on making this a loop where I will increment that value to print other images)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

mysql_connect   ...
mysql_select_db   ...

$id = 2;
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];
echo $image;


?>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "the reason I set $id = 2 is because I plan on making this a loop where I will increment that value to print other images)" You mean you are going to query the database in a loop -> bad idea.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: Side Note: Why `SELECT *` if you only use `image`?  Just `SELECT image`.  The rest of the columns are just wasted resources.

Comment: this as it is does nothing, i'm going to change this so that it store the location to SQL which I found will make this wildly easier/possible... I will also check those links out, I am using an older book atm and that's probably why i'm a bit outdated

Comment: David, I caught that too, just a mistake it was meant to be image

Answer (score 2):

First, some caveats:

- Don't use the `mysql_*` functions
- Don't store images in SQL.  Store the location.  (You may already be doing this).

If you're storing the location, you'll need to add `<img>` tags to the `echo`

```
echo "<img src='$image'>";
```

Comment: Full SQL message: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to echo the markup also?

```
echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
```